# Do the following capture group notation mean something to Perl

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

In the following why does the condition evaluate to `false`?

```
$_ = "aa11bb";  
if(/(.)\111/){  
    print "It matched!\n";  
}
```

Does `\11` or `\111` have special meaning that `Perl` can not "see" `\1`?

Answer (score 6):

Actually Perl is interpreting  `\111` as an octal, which is  not found in your
string.  It would  only consider  two or  more digits  backreferences if  such
number of groups is found. To avoid the ambiguity, use `\g` or `\g{}`. Quoting
the docs ([perlre - Capture Groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups)):

> The \g and \k notations were introduced  in Perl 5.10.0. Prior to that there
>   were no named nor relative numbered capture groups. Absolute numbered groups
>   were referred to using  \1 , \2 , etc., and this  notation is still accepted
>   (and likely always will  be). But it leads to some  ambiguities if there are
>   more  than 9  capture groups,  as \10  could mean  either the  tenth capture
>   group,  or the  character whose  ordinal  in octal  is 010  (a backspace  in
>   ASCII). Perl resolves this ambiguity  by interpreting \10 as a backreference
>   only if at least 10 left parentheses  have opened before it. Likewise \11 is
>   a backreference only if at least  11 left parentheses have opened before it.
>   And so on. \1 through \9 are always interpreted as backreferences. There are
>   several  examples below  that illustrate  these  perils. You  can avoid  the
>   ambiguity by always using  \g{} or \g if you mean  capturing groups; and for
>   octal constants always  using \o{} , or  for \077 and below,  using 3 digits
>   padded with leading zeros, since a leading zero implies an octal constant.

Comment: I'm reading the docs but it's not completely clear for me. If `\111` is interpreted as octal, then `\11` should work and it doesn't. And also `\001` should work because it's the octal number of first backreference and it neither matches. What did I miss?

Comment: @Birei It's an octal *character* reference to character `0111` = character 73 = `"I"`. So your pattern matches any character followed by the letter I.

Comment: @hobbs: Thank you. I've already understood that point, but what about the `\11`?

Comment: @Birei `\11` will look for character `011` octal = character 9 = tab (unless your pattern has at least eleven left-parentheses in it). Only `\1` through `\9` are automatically backreferences in regexes.

Comment: @hobbs: I thought that the one digit backreference had priority over the octal interpretation, unless a leading zero. All clear now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It's treating the `\111` as a single item, because there's nothing separating the `\1` from the `11`. If you use the `/x` modifier to allow spacing you can remove the ambiguity:

```
if(/(.)\1 11/x) { ...
```

Comment: or `if(/(.)\g{1}11/)`

Comment: @Matt that will only work in perls 5.10 or better. A lot of us are stuck in 5.8.8.

Comment: Yeah you're right good call. We have it here for reference now :) I'm pretty sure Perl 5.8.8 is default on Red Hat 5 which is supported until 2017 (or something) so we may have many programmers stuck there for a while.